# Reassign system modifier key

Tags: debian, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, remapping

In macOS, the "system modifier key" (the key for system-wide OS shortcuts like copy, paste, etc.) is `cmd`, which is separate from the `ctrl` key. This means that the `cmd` key can be used for things like opening new browser tabs and copy/pasting system-wide, and the `ctrl` key can be used for navigating text emacs style (e.g. `ctrl-a` to go to start of line anywhere in the OS).

Since switching to Debian, I've been extremely frustrated by not having this separation. It means that my muscle-memory `ctrl-a` to go to the start of the line instead selects all text (like `cmd-a` would on a mac).

Is there any way to reassign the duties of the `ctrl` key to a different key? This does not mean remap `ctrl` to a different key on the keyboard; I still want `ctrl` to exist, but I don't want it to be used for things like copy/paste, I want a different modifier key to do this and leave `ctrl` free for emacs-style commands.

I understand that this may be difficult to do in all cases, but even if I could make it work in Chrome, terminal, and some IDEs that'd be good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I've found in the past few days that can be adapted to this use case is [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey). It allows you to (among other things) run python scripts on specific key combinations to modify their actions. This can be used to mimic a macOS keyboard in Linux (where `ctrl` is its own key, and `cmd` in this case can be considered synonymous with `alt` or `win`).

For example, to change `ctrl-a` to go to the beginning of the line (emacs style), and use `alt-a` for select all, I wrote the following script:

```
import re

if re.match('.*Gnome-terminal', window.get_active_class()):
  keyboard.send_keys("<ctrl>+a")
else:
  keyboard.send_keys("<home>")
```

This allows `ctrl-a` to retain its behavior in the terminal, but go to the beginning of the line is all other programs (e.g. Chrome and IntelliJ). In AutoKey this is bound to `ctrl-a` and runs whenever that shortcut is pressed.

Another example is using `alt-w` to close tabs (e.g. in Chrome, IntelliJ and the Terminal). This can be done with this script bound to `alt+w`:

```
import re

if re.match('.*(Gnome-terminal|jetbrains-clion)', window.get_active_class()):
  keyboard.send_keys("<ctrl>+<shift>+w")
else:
  keyboard.send_keys("<ctrl>+w")
```

Answer (score 1):

- Command + Space
- Search for Keyboard (also you can go from settings -> Keyboard)
- Select Subtab - Keyboard
- Click on Modifier keys
- Change as you wish. Hope this helps.
  Here is screen shot of modifier keys!!

[Modifer Keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PsUO.png)

Comment: I believe that you might have misunderstood the question.

Comment: Right, this is not what I meant.